# Editing the filename in a HTML file input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I am trying to prevent IE from sending the full file path to the server on a file upload.  So I am trying to parse out the filename.  In my HTML I have:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="cutsheet" data-url="ws/cutsheet/representation">
```

So if the value attribute is "c:\folder\file.txt", I want to change that to "file.txt".  I have the following javascript:

```
$('#fileupload').change(function() {
    var index = this.value.lastIndexOf('\\');
    this.value = this.value.substring(index + 1);
    alert(this.value);
});
```

However, my alert shows "c:\folder\file.txt".  Can I not set the value attribute's value?

Comment: Not for a file input.

Comment: what is it sending the path to the server???

Comment: Just edit it on the server, you can not touch the value...It only sets the path when the browser is in the right security zones.

Answer (score 0):

Try `split()`

```
$('#fileupload').change(function(e) {
   var input = $(this).val();
   var pieces = input.split('\\');
   alert(pieces[pieces.length-1]);
});
```

#### [Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/V5Qd8/](http://jsfiddle.net/V5Qd8/)